# Удалить выбранный элемент

Tags: java, android

В моём адаптере существует метод getView, где реализован метод удаления элемента, по его нажатию:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView = (View) convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            gridView = new View(context);
            if (imageUploads.get(position).getOutputMetadata().getFilename().equals("null")) {
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_upload_default, null);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.iv_upload);
                imageView.setImageResource(resource);
            } else {
                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_upload, null);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.iv_upload);
                ImageView closeView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.photo_close_btn);
                final ProgressWheel progress = (ProgressWheel) gridView.findViewById(R.id.loader_photo);
                ImageUpload mobile = imageUploads.get(position);
                if (imageUploads.get(position).isLoadImage())
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_RESIZE + 150 + "x" + 150 + "/" + StringUtil.URLADS_THUMBLER_IMAGE + mobile.getOutputMetadata().getFilename())
                            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess() {
                                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError() {

                                }
                            });
                else {
                    File f = new File(imageUploads.get(position).getPath());
                    Picasso.with(context)
                            .load(f)
                            .into(imageView);
                }
                closeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        imageUploads.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return gridView;
    }
```

Но по нажатию на кнопку, удаляется последний добавленный элемент.
К примеру, мы добавили 5 значений в следующем порядке: A, B, C, D, E. После чего нажимаем к примеру на удалить C, но удаляется последний добавленный элемент, то есть Е, потом D и только потом  значение С.

Вспомогательный метод(у меня во фрагменте)-где постарался реализовать следующую логику:

```
public void onSuccess(ImageUpload t, Response response) {
                Log.d("passs", length + " " + mSelectPath.size() + "");
                controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(length - mSelectPath.size()).setLoadImage(true);
                controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().get(length - mSelectPath.size()).setOutputMetadata(t.getOutputMetadata());
                mSelectPath.remove(0);
                if (controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().size() > 10)
                    controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().remove(controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().size() - 1);
                adapterForm.notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (mSelectPath.size() > 0 && (length - mSelectPath.size()) < 10)
                    uploadPhoto(mSelectPath, position, length);
            }
```

Как возможно определить нажатие по конкретному элементу?
Возможно ли определить позицию пункта в списке, после чего удалять конкретно его, зная информацию о пункте списка?

Comment: откуда берется переменная position?

Comment: Ваш вопрос непонятен. У вас, наверное, всё это в адапетере происходит и тогда у вас есть position. и проблемы тогда нет. Но она у вас есть... Попробуйте более полно сформулировать суть проблемы и приведите конкретный случай её возникновения

Comment: @metalurgus первая position у меня объявлена в адаптере(в методе getView), а вторая во фрагменте(в методе uploadPhoto).

Comment: а какая из них используется тут: `imageUploads.remove(position);`

Comment: @metalurgus первая и используется, которая в методе getView.

Comment: controlList.setOnItemClickListener(..); попробуй использывать

Comment: Выложите полный код `getView()`

Comment: Можете попробовать заменить `imageUploads.remove(position);` на `imageUploads.remove(mobile);`, чтобы точно удалялся объект, в случае если индексы почему-то сдвинулись

Comment: @metalurgus предложил сделать его final, после чего начал жить своей жизнью(удаляет не корректно, или вообще не удаляет). Проблема еще в том что удаляет саму иконку(добавления фотографии).